# knife-windows: Network Error: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known (windows:22)

Tags: windows, plugins, chef-infra, knife

I have an Ubuntu workstation and i'm trying to bootstrap a windows node.  The windows node has ssh open on port 2222.  I've been following http://docs.opscode.com/plugin_knife_windows.html.

```
ateetor@ateetor-virtual-machine:~/chef/chef-repo$ sudo gem install knife-windows --http-proxy=[REMOVED]
Successfully installed knife-windows-0.5.12
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for knife-windows-0.5.12...
Installing RDoc documentation for knife-windows-0.5.12...

ateetor@ateetor-virtual-machine:~/chef/chef-repo$ sudo knife bootstrap windows ssh 10.29.3.114 -x chef -P SSHuser1! -N test -p 2222 -VV
DEBUG: Looking for bootstrap template in /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap
DEBUG: Found bootstrap template in /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap
Bootstrapping Chef on windows
DEBUG: Adding windows
DEBUG: establishing connection to windows:2222
ERROR: Network Error: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Check your knife configuration and network settings
```

To me what that looks like is it's trying to use the word windows as part of the IP; however my syntax matches the guide so i don't know why.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the output it's running the generic bootstrap template.

> Looking for bootstrap template in /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.4.4/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap

Most likely there is an installation or ruby environment issue resolving the knife-windows gem.

When correctly configured you should see:

> Looking for bootstrap template in /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/knife-windows-0.5.12/lib/chef/knife/bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

The only fix I have found is to use knife from a windows workstation instead of a linux one.

Answer (score 0):

```
knife bootstrap windows winrm 111.22.33.44.compute-1.amazonaws.com -x Administrator -P "asdklfj329" -N "windows-2008-551"
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue.One of the reasons for this might be you knife-windows gem package is not installed in expected location.

knife-windows resolves target hostname ,if its not properly installed winrm knife cant resolve targetname.So to overcome this install knife-windows as below

To install the knife windows plugin using RubyGems, run the following command:

> `$ /opt/chef/embedded/bin/gem install knife-windows`

if properly installed you should be able to find knife-windows at

`/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/`